# AWS Cognito user migration email bug

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am testing Cognito for replacement of our existing auth code and have found a bug. I have a user pool and implemented the user migration lambda to test the migration process. The user pool is setup to use email as username.

From my client I login with existing credentials, the user migration lambda does the following:

```
event['response']['userAttributes'] = {
            'preferred_username': "migrated guy"
            }
event["finalUserStatus"] = "CONFIRMED"
event["messageAction"] = "SUPPRESS"
return event
```

Login is successful and my user is migrated to Cognito. However, the user immediately receives and email with the subject "Your temporary password" and body "Your username is *****@******.com and temporary password is ********." The temporary password in the email is one generated by Cognito, not the one entered/migrated. I can subsequently log in again with the original password while the one from the email does not work. I have tried this multiple times with the same result. This happens whether or not the migrated password meets my password strength requirements.

Is there at least a way to avoid having this erroneous email sent? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manage to get this resolved, the `finalUserStatus` and `messageAction` need to be set on `event.response` instead of on `event`:

```
event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED";
event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
```

The event structure can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-user-migration

Comment: Thank you. I'm coming back to this project shortly and your answer is incredibly helpful.